# Finding time it takes to load links with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a link checker that finds the time it takes reach links on a page. I've created an ajax function that logs the time it has taken to reach success.

```
var col = new Array();
var counter = 0;
var myAjax= function(temp, start){
    $.ajax({            
    url:$(this).attr("href"), 
    success: function () { 
        var end = performance.now();
        console.log(temp);
        console.log(performance.now()-start)

    }, 
    error: function (jqXHR, status, er) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 404) { 

            console.log("connection failed");               
        }
  } 
 });
 }
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {
    $("a").each(function(){     
    var temp = $(this).not("#next").attr("href");
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(temp===undefined){
        return;
    }
    col.push(temp);
    var start = 0;
    myFunction(myAjax, temp);   

 }
)}

function myFunction (callback, temp){
  start = performance.now();
  callback(temp, start);
}
}
);
```

The problem is, this doesn't seem to register page load time. Also, the times seem to be incrementally increasing each run by ~3 ms. How can I calculate the time it takes for links to load en masse?

Many thanks.

Comment: Move the `start` variable into higher context (declare it globally). Currently it's not visible from the success callback.

Comment: ok i managed to figure this out by implementing performance.timing and using the commands loadEventEnd. Is there a way to use this to calculate link load time?

Comment: It depends on what you consider `link load time`: for example if it's the entire page load with all dependencies (pictures and scripts) then the only solution is to actually open the links in a background tab and measure the time until `load` event or chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted. Otherwise it's not clear what the problem is besides the wrong variable scope.

Comment: hm...but each time the ajax function is called, the variable start is passed through the parameters. i think the start time is being found appropriately. doesn't the ajax success function only act to ping the website? does it calculate how long it would take to load?

Comment: 1. In `myFunction` the variable `start` is created inside `window` and then reused for each link. 2. on-success measures only html load time

Comment: yes, i would like it to reuse for each link so that i can calculate the load time for each link. also, is there a way to measure load time with all dependencies?

Comment: 1. `Reuse` means that the variable is overwritten and loses its previous value. Make sure you understand how variable scoping in Javascript works. 2. I already told you that.